# Kde titlebar icon customisation, to add resize icon

Tags: kde4

I am using kde 5 with oxygen theme.

I like this theme. However, like most themes, lacks a resize button in the window title bar.

I have looked into customizing the theme, but have had no luck:
I can not find where the title-bar icons are stored.
I can not figure out any documentation. All of which seems to start out simple then suddenly drops deep in, it assumes that I know what it is talking about, it does not even say what language the code is in, or where it goes.

Can anyone tell me where to start?
Do I just need to add an icon? If so how?
Do I need to do more to enable the functionality? (note the functionality is found in the horribly ugly “BII preview” theme, but non of the nicer themes. )

---

I am using Gnu/Linux, Debian 10 (Buster), and plasma 5

Comment: Sorry for asking a potentially stupid question: What is a "resize button" supposed to do? You resize windows on their edges, so what do you need a button for?

Comment: @Philippos good question. Why: Because if the edges are small, then they are hard to grab. If they are big then they wast too much screen space. I use the border glow to be able to see the edge, but want smaller borders to save space. What: I twm (the original one, that came with X11), you don't grab the edge. There is a button in the title bar. You click it, and move the mouse, the first X and first Y border that you hit, become attached to the mouse for resize.

Answer (score 0):

**KDE Documentation:**

- KDE v5 theming documentation is available [here](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/Theme) and [here](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/ThemeDetails)
- KDE v5 window decorations documentation is available [here](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/kwindecoration/index.html)

**KDE 5 Theme:**

KDE themes may not include the icons for the title bar (window decorations), this is managed by the `kwin_x11` window decoration; this theming feature is configurable under:

KDE System Settings Panel (`systemsettings5`) **>** Appearance/Application Style **>** Window Decoration

You can as well download other themes from there with the button `Get New Decorations...` as shown on the [linked](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/kwindecoration/index.html) documentation.

Oxygen theme do include window decorations and if it's not displayed you should be able to select the proper decorations (button skins) under `systemsettings5` (KDE System Settings Panel) otherwise you may be missing the package [kwin-decoration-oxygen](https://debian.pkgs.org/10/debian-main-amd64/kwin-decoration-oxygen_5.14.5-1_amd64.deb.html)

Window decoration themes are location in multiple folder (this may differ depending on the used distro)

```
/usr/lib64/qt5/qml/org/kde/kwin/
/usr/share/kwin/decorations/
~/.local/share/kwin/decorations/
etc.
```

For more detail on how to implement the decorations style you can have a look at the [oxygen sources](https://cgit.kde.org/oxygen.git) (note that oxygen theme do include window decorations)

Note: main themes are stored in `~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/` and  or system wide, on `/usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/` (this may differ depending on the used distro).

Comment: Not tried it yet, but was back here (searching for something else, and decided to have a look). New addresses: https://develop.kde.org/docs/extend/plasma/theme/quickstart/ https://develop.kde.org/docs/extend/plasma/theme/theme-details/